# How can I log into Redmine (LDAP) once my active directory password changes?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, redmine

My active directory password changed, now I can't log into Redmine (0.9.4) via LDAP.  I haven't installed plugins, so what gives?

Comment: Did you wait for replication? Sometime, Domain Controller can take up to 1 hours to replicate between each others.

Comment: We solved it already over at ServerFault...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dupe of [this issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/169412/how-can-i-log-into-redmine-ldap-once-my-active-directory-password-changes/169423#169423) over at ServerFault...

What account were you using to authenticate to LDAP? If the password expires or is changed for the account being used by the LDAP component to verify your account, then you will get rejected every time. The only remedy i had was either to log on as a local administrator, if one exists, and update the LDAP config, or go into the database manually and update the record in the auth_sources table.